# How to extract a value within single quotes from a string?

Tags: bash, grep, cut

I am trying to get the `value` from the string:

```
define('__mypassword', 'value');
```

I am trying to use `cut` and `grep` for this.

```
grep "__mypassword'" myfile.php | cut -d ',' -f 2
```

This returns `'value');`

I do not need the quotes or braces or semi column. How do I take the value out without using multiple `cut` statements?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Juse use `awk`!

```
$ awk -F"'" '/__mypassword/{print $4}' <<< "define('__mypassword', 'value');"
value
```

This sets the field separator to the single quote. This way, it is just a matter of printing the 4th element, which is the one after the 3rd quote. `/__mypassword/` acts as `grep "__mypassword"`.

In case you also need to match the single quote, use `/__mypassword'\''/` (a bit picky, you need to close the `awk` statement to include a single quote).

Answer (score 3):

Don't count commas, count single quotes:

```
grep "__mypassword'" myfile.php | cut -d"'" -f4
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kent$  grep -oP "[^']+(?='\))" <<<"define('__mypassword', 'value');"
value
```